# Can I program an Eclipse RCP application in a .NET language?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Heresy? Possible through the dark magic of [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/)? Would I just write a lot of C# code that had to pretend to be Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get your question previously. The short answer is NO. In order to write a Eclipse RCP application, you need to write plugins, which in current present, can only be written in Java. However, Eclipse 4.0 (e4) project promises to support plugins written in other languages, let us see if C# is one of the them!

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume here, but I'm almost certain that SWT (the UI framework for Eclipse) is going to break with IKVM. The whole OSGi plug-in concept will most likely not work with that tool. Have you experimented a little already?

In general, why would anyone want to do that?

Comment: haven't experimented. we've got eclipse rcp fanatics in a group we interact with, and it might be nice to plug in some of our existing .NET goodness into their application. a mental experiment more than anything...